# Display image using bitmap in listview, android?

Tags: android, image, listview, bitmap

I have 2 activities.
In the first activity i am loading the image and data using lazyloading.
In the 2nd activity i am using a normal custom listview.
I am fetching the bitmap of the selected listview element from the 1st activity.
Now i want to preview that bitmap in every listview element of second activity.
How to do that?

Comment: 1. http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/ 2. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/507651/Customized-Android-ListView-with-Image-and-Text

Comment: Your question is not clear exactly.

Comment: it will also help you for lazy loading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview